# Efficient way to partition a list into equivalence classes given an equivalence class function (not an equivalence relation)?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Suppose I have a `list` of elements and a function `f` which maps each element of `list` to an equivalence class of elements (which should be a sublist of `list`). What's an efficient way to partition `list` into these equivalence classes?

(Note that this is not the same question as [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244802/most-efficient-way-to-find-equivalence-classes-of-an-equivalence-relation), as that assumes we start with an equivalence relation `equiv` mapping pairs of elements of list to `True` or `False`.)

A naive way would be to simply use `GatherBy[list, f]`, but if the equivalence classes are big or `f` is hard to compute, this is wasting a lot of computational resources—we should be able to check to see if each successive element of `list` is in an already-produced equivalence class, and skip it if so.

Here's one attempt that naively implements that idea (and performs no checks to make sure `f` behaves the way you say it does):

```
EquivalenceClasses0[list_List, f_] := Module[{classes = {}},
  Scan[x |-> If[! MemberQ[classes, x, {2}], AppendTo[classes, f[x]]], list];
  classes]
```

Here's an approach that does it more functionally:

```
EquivalenceClasses1[list_List, f_] :=
  Fold[{classes, x} |-> If[! MemberQ[classes, x, {2}], Append[classes, f[x]], classes], {}, list]
```

These seem to perform very similarly. But, obviously, I don't like the use of `Append` and `AppendTo`. However, `Sow` and `Reap` can't be used on the top level, because each computation depends on the previous ones, so we'd have to continuously `Reap` (which would defeat the purpose, I think).

I tried a few alternative approaches: using a `Flat` head instead of `Append`, customizing the `MemberQ` function and using nested heads of the form `w[x_w, y_]`, then collapsing them at the end, as well as naively "allocating memory" for the list via a constant array of the same length as `list`, keeping track of how big each class is, and then using `TakeList` to split it up correctly. But I feel as though I'm missing a "nice" or "canonical" way to do this. Any ideas? (I'll provide an example problem to benchmark things and my attempts so far below, if you're interested!)

---

#### Examples, benchmarking functions & attempts so far

So, here's an example of the sort of `f` I'm talking about, which gets the set of all row and column permutations of a given matrix (i.e. the orbit under the standard action of $S_n \times S_k$, given bases):

```
MatrixPermutations[m_?MatrixQ] := 
 Sort @ DeleteDuplicates @ Flatten[Map[Transpose]@*Permutations@*Transpose /@ Permutations[m], 1]

(* Example: *)
MatrixForm /@ MatrixPermutations[{{1,0},{1,1}}]

(* Row and column permutations of 2x2 0-1 matrices: *)
Map[MatrixForm] /@ EquivalenceClasses1[Tuples[{0, 1}, {2, 2}], MatrixPermutations]
```

Here are all the `EquivalenceClass` functions I came up with in a block, including those above.

```
(* Procedural, AppendTo: *)

EquivalenceClasses0[list_List, f_] := Module[{classes = {}},
  Scan[x |-> If[! MemberQ[classes, x, {2}], AppendTo[classes, f[x]]], list];
  classes]

(* Functional, Append: *)

EquivalenceClasses1[list_List, f_] :=
  Fold[{classes, x} |-> If[! MemberQ[classes, x, {2}], Append[classes, f[x]], classes], {}, list]

(* Functional, nesting wrapper with new MemberQ: *)

wMemberQ[w[], elem_] = False;

wMemberQ[w[x_, y_], elem_] := MemberQ[y, elem, 1] || wMemberQ[x, elem]

EquivalenceClasses2[list_List, f_] := 
 Block[{w}, (w = Sequence; #) & @ {Fold[{wclasses, x} |-> 
      If[! wMemberQ[wclasses, x], w[wclasses, f[x]], wclasses], w[], list]}]

(* Functional, Flat attribute for appending: *)

SetAttributes[ww, Flat]

EquivalenceClasses3[list_List, f_] := 
 List @@ 
  Fold[{wclasses, x} |-> If[! MemberQ[wclasses, x, {2}], ww[wclasses, f[x]], wclasses], 
       ww[], list]

(* Procedural, line up results in pre-allocated list with Set and Span, then TakeList: *)

EquivalenceClasses4[list_List, f_] := 
 Module[{v, s, n = 1, n1 = 0, i = 1, nlist = ConstantArray[0, Length[list]]},
  s = ConstantArray[v, Length[list]]; 
  Scan[x |-> 
    If[!MemberQ[s, x, 1],
       (class |-> (s[[#1 ;; #2]] = class) &[n, n + (n1 = Length[class]) - 1])@f[x];
         n = n + n1; nlist[[i]] = n1; i++;],
    list];
  TakeList[s, Take[nlist, i - 1]]]

(* Functional, line up results in pre-allocated list with SubsetMap and Range, then TakeList: *)

EquivalenceClasses5[list_List, f_] := 
 Module[{n = 1, n1 = 0, i = 1, nlist = ConstantArray[0, Length[list]]}, 
  TakeList[#, Take[nlist, i - 1]] & @
   Fold[{s, x} |-> 
     If[!MemberQ[s, x, 1],
        (n = n + n1; nlist[[i]] = n1; i++; #) &[
          (class |-> SubsetMap[class &, s, Range[n, n + (n1 = Length[class]) - 1]])@f[x]], s], 
    ConstantArray[0, Length[list]],
    list]]

(* Procedural, use individual definitions to hold values by Set and MapIndexed, then TakeList: *)

EquivalenceClasses6[list_List, f_] := 
 Module[{v, s, nminus = 0, n1 = 0, i = 1, nlist = ConstantArray[0, Length[list]]},
  s = Array[v, Length[list]]; 
  Scan[x |->
    If[!MemberQ[s, x, 1],
       MapIndexed[
         Construct[Set, v[# + nminus] & @@ #2, #1] &, (n1 = Length[#]; #) &@f[x],
         {1}]; nminus = nminus + n1; nlist[[i]] = n1; i++;], 
    list];
  TakeList[s, Take[nlist, i - 1]]]

(* Procedural, use individual definitions to hold values by broadcasted Set, then TakeList: *)

EquivalenceClasses7[list_List, f_] := 
 Module[{v, s, n = 1, n1 = 0, i = 1, nlist = ConstantArray[0, Length[list]]},
  s = Array[v, Length[list]]; 
  Scan[x |-> 
    If[!MemberQ[s, x, 1], 
       Construct[Set, Array[v, n1 = Length[#], n], #] &@f[x];
       n = n + n1; nlist[[i]] = n1; i++;],
    list];
  TakeList[s, Take[nlist, i - 1]]]
```

Check they agree on some input:

```
heads = {EquivalenceClasses0, EquivalenceClasses1, 
   EquivalenceClasses2, EquivalenceClasses3, EquivalenceClasses4, 
   EquivalenceClasses5, EquivalenceClasses6, EquivalenceClasses7};

t = Tuples[{0, 1}, {3, 3}];

SameQ @@ Through[heads[t, MatrixPermutations]]

(* Output should be True *)
```

I timed these and visualized the times with the following code, plotting input size along the x axis and time on the y axis (both on a log scale).

```
(* Function that enumerates pairs of integers up to symmetry
   (for use in the second argument of Tuples): *)

symmetricGrid2DStep[1] = {1, 1};

symmetricGrid2DStep[n_Integer] := 
 symmetricGrid2DStep[n] =
   (If[#1 + 1 > #2 - 1, {1, #1 + #2}, {#1 + 1, #2 - 1}] & @@ symmetricGrid2DStep[n - 1])

(* Function which produces lists of pairs {<length of input>, <time spent>} for each head: *)

Get01MatrixTimings[heads : {__}, sizecutoff_Integer : 20000, stepcutoff_Integer : 20, retime : (True | False) : False] :=
  (If[retime, 
   Quiet[Get01MatrixTimings[heads, sizecutoff, stepcutoff, False] =., Unset::norep]];
   
  Get01MatrixTimings[heads, sizecutoff, stepcutoff, False] =

   Module[{t, step, n = 4, counting = False},
     First /@ Last @ Reap[
       While[n <= stepcutoff,
        step = symmetricGrid2DStep[n]; 
        If[! MemberQ[step, 1] && 2^(Times @@ step) <= sizecutoff,
         counting = False; t = Tuples[{0, 1}, symmetricGrid2DStep[n]];
         Do[
          With[{head = heads[[p]]}, 
           Sow[{2^(Times @@ step), First@RepeatedTiming[head[t, MatrixPermutations];]}, 
             head];],
          {p, Length[heads]}],
         If[First@step == 1, If[counting, Break[], counting = True]]];
         n++;];
       If[n == stepcutoff, Print["stepcutoff met"]];,
       heads]
    ])

LogLogPlot01MatrixTimings[heads : {__}, sizecutoff_Integer : 20000, stepcutoff_Integer : 20, retime : (True | False) : False, opts___Rule] := 
 ListLogLogPlot[
  Get01MatrixTimings[heads, sizecutoff, stepcutoff, retime], 
  PlotLegends -> heads, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
  opts]
```

Which produced the following plot (don't run this—it'll take a while!):

```
LogLogPlot01MatrixTimings[heads, True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: A log-log plot showing functions 0, 1, 2, and 3 having middle-of-the-road performance, functions 6 and 7 having worse performance, and functions 4 and five having the best performance, with 4 winning by a hair.]

So it seems that of my attempts, `EquivalenceClasses4` is the winner by a hair! That was

```
EquivalenceClasses4[list_List, f_] := 
 Module[{v, s, n = 1, n1 = 0, i = 1, 
   nlist = ConstantArray[0, Length[list]]},
  s = ConstantArray[v, Length[list]]; 
  Scan[x |-> 
    If[!MemberQ[s, x, 1],
       (class |-> (s[[#1 ;; #2]] = class) &[n, n + (n1 = Length[class]) - 1])@f[x];
         n = n + n1; nlist[[i]] = n1; i++;],
    list];
  TakeList[s, Take[nlist, i - 1]]]
```

It's interesting that the procedural one beats the functional version ever so slightly. Note that it does manage to beat `GatherBy` by a little, despite not being nice and C-optimized:

```
SameQ @@ Through[{EquivalenceClasses4, GatherBy}[t, MatrixPermutations]]

(* Output: True *)

LogLogPlot01MatrixTimings[{EquivalenceClasses4, GatherBy}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: The same plot as earlier, but it's just GatherBy being beaten by EquivalenceClasses4 a little.]

(These performance graphs could be improved; I'm sure there's some dependence on how big the equivalence classes are (and thus how many of them there are).)

Still, `EquivalenceClasses4` looks pretty ugly and ad-hoc. Can it be improved? And am I missing some super-obvious implementation?

(To easily check your own function against my best one, redefine `heads` to include it—e.g. `heads = {EquivalenceClasses4, yourFunction};`—check it agrees (`t = Tuples[{0, 1}, {3, 3}]; SameQ @@ Through[heads[t, MatrixPermutations]]`)—and then run some `RepeatedTiming`s on it, or run `LogLogPlot01MatrixTimings[heads, True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large]`.)

---

#### Graphs of answers so far

Here's the performance of @Coolwater's answer:

[image: My 4th attempt vs. Coolwater's attempt; coolwater's attempt is significantly faster!]

Very nice! :)

(I also noticed that if we have guarantees that `f` is well-behaved, then we don't need the intersection in Coolwater's answer. This improves performance by a hair for large inputs!)

```
EquivalenceClassesSE01[list_List, f_] := 
 Reap[NestWhile[Complement[#, Sow[f[First[#]]]] &, 
    list, # =!= {} &]][[2, 1]]
```

[image: my 4th attempt, coolwater's attempt, and a modified coolwater attempt, which is just slightly lower]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If neither the order of the classes nor the elements within each class matters:

```
classes = Reap[NestWhile[Complement[#, Sow[MatrixPermutations[First[#]] ⋂ #]] &, t, # =!= {} &]][[2, 1]];
```

The order of `GatherBy[t, MatrixPermutations]` can still be restored:

```
With[{order = Sort /@ SortBy[Replace[classes, PositionIndex[t][[All, 1]], {2}], Min]},
   TakeList[t[[Catenate[order]]], Length /@ order]] === GatherBy[t, MatrixPermutations]
(* True *)
```

In `MatrixPermutations` the loop `Map[Transpose]` can be omitted by transposing the matrix at the beginning, and `Union` is the same as `Sort@*DeleteDuplicates`:

```
MatrixPermutations[m_?MatrixQ] := Union @@ Permutations@*Transpose /@ Permutations[Transpose[m]]
```

Comment: Very nice! That clearly outperforms mine! :) I'll still leave the question open for a bit in case someone wants to share another approach

Comment: In fact, as long as we have guarantees that `f` behaves like an equivalence class function, we shouldn't need the intersection—the equivalence class of any element in still in `#` (such as `First[#]`) in that loop shouldn't include any prior elements. If it did, then `First[#]` would have been removed as part of *their* equivalence class. This increases the performance dramatically for large inputs!

Comment: oops, no it doesn't—I had a typo. :) it only helps a little bit

Comment: Do you mind if I ask—did you have any particular reasoning or rationale to think that this construction would be faster? or did you just try it and it worked?